# How to rename a newman csv report generated using the npm package newman-reporter-csv

Tags: postman, newman

I am generating a csv report for the collection run using newman. I am using newman-reporter-csv package to generate this report. The report name is in the format newman-run-report-2019-04-21-04-19-16-224-0.csv. Is there a way I can save this report with a different name (e.g TestSuite1_Dev) while I am executing the newman command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `--reporter-csv-export` flag and specify the file name and location.

For example:

`--reporter-csv-export ./pathName/TestSuite1_Dev.csv`